# Git cloning error: 'fatal: multiple updates for ... ref not allowed'

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I'm getting an error when trying to `git clone` a repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/laradock/laradock.git                                                 
Cloning into 'laradock'...                                                                           
remote: Enumerating objects: 8606, done.                                                             
remote: Total 8606 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 8606                                  
Receiving objects: 100% (8606/8606), 8.09 MiB | 6.92 MiB/s, done.                                    
Resolving deltas: 100% (4551/4551), done.                                                            
fatal: multiple updates for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/LaraDock-ToolBox' not allowed
```

This is happening for any repo I try to clone. I am running `git version 2.21.0` installed via `homebrew`.

Has anyone else encoutered this issue? Not really sure whats going on here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, I seem to have fixed the issue. Removing the following from my .gitconfig seemed to do the trick, but I am not sure why:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I know that `git v2.21.0` was just released a few days ago, so maybe something changed under the hood. I need to check out the release notes.

Anyways, hope this can help someone!

Comment: Helps me a lot! My environment `$ git --version
git version 2.21.0`

Comment: You certainly did. Thank you!

Comment: The command to do so for me was `git config --global --unset remote.origin.fetch`

Comment: Also, be sure to remove `fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` from your .gitconfig

Comment: `git config --global --unset remote.origin.fetch` woked for me too. (as Stephen Saucier said). I have not found any [remote "orign"] in my git config (in C:\ProgramData\Git\config)

Comment: On git-for-windows the default settings file is `%userprofile%\.gitconfig`

Comment: `git config --global --unset remote.origin.fetch` works for me.  git version 2.28.0 on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
[remote "origin"]
  tagopt = --tags
  # modify next line:
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

  push = +refs/archive/*:refs/archive/*
```

with:

```
[remote "origin"]
  tagopt = --tags

  # modified this line:
  fetch = +refs/archive/*:refs/archive/*

  push = +refs/archive/*:refs/archive/*
```

And it fixed the issue. `git branch -a` still shows all remote branches

other potentially interesting things from my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
  ignorecase = false
  fileMode = false
  eol = lf
  autocrlf = false

[filter "lfs"]
  process = git-lfs filter-process
  required = true
  clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
  smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f

[uploadpack]
  allowReachableSHA1InWant = true

[gc]
  autodetach = false
  pruneExpire = never
  reflogExpire = never
  auto = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. But instead, after checking my .gitconfig i realized that I had 3 entries of

> fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*

So the solution was simply to delete all the extra entries and to be left only with one entry.

I haven't really checked why that happened, neither on what the problem was, but it seems that base on the remote `origin` , git first fetched the files, and on time to resolve the second and third entries still requested the same files, resulting in multiple updates of the same repo from same origin.