# Make a clone of GitHub git repository with refs/pull with Git 2.22.1 (fatal: multiple updates for ref)

Tags: git, github

I used to be able to make a mirror of GitHub repo, including pull request PRs, with:

```
git clone --mirror --bare --config remote.origin.fetch="+refs/pull/*:refs/pull/*" https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git/
```

However, with the most recent version of Git this no longer works:

```
Cloning into bare repository '/data/git-mirror/pytorch.git'...
fatal: multiple updates for ref 'refs/pull/100/head' not allowed
```

Is there a way to do this with the most recent version of Git?  The guidance for [Git cloning error: 'fatal: multiple updates for ... ref not allowed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922704/git-cloning-error-fatal-multiple-updates-for-ref-not-allowed) suggests removing the fetch line, which I certainly believe would work, but it would mean that I don't actually get the PR refs (which I absolutely want!)

Comment: `--mirror` sets the default fetch refspec to `refs/*:refs/*`; your `--config` adds another one, and the two refspecs overlap on `refs/pull/*`. The actual overlap itself is harmless but apparently the newest Git objects, while apparently older ones don't.

Comment: I mean, I can remove the `--config` but then I don't get `refs/pull` mirrored...

Comment: With `--mirror`, you *do* get `refs/pull` mirrored, because the default refspec is now `refs/*:refs/*`.